# Django unit tests mock

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, paramiko

I came to the ***mock*** lib which I never used before in tests. I need the response from server (the server is not actually there) if it is online or not. First of all I need to check that server IP and then check the state of it with the response of TRUE or FALSE. *Server.object* should come from *models.py* so I guess I need to start using mock lib here. Maybe some of you could explain me or show me few examples of getting fake response from 'mock'server. I have read Django testing , mock lib official documentation but none of them gave me enough info how to simulate response from fake server.

Code example:

```
def ssh_server(server_list, timeout=200):
    online = False
    response = []
    server_state = []
    timeout_stamp = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeout)
    for obj_id in server_list:
        server = models.Server.objects.get(id=obj_id)
        ip = server.ip
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        while True:
            try:
                client.connect(ip, username='root')
                online = True
            except:
                online = False
```

Comment: How does your app usually conect to the server? The requests module? If it does you need to mock that. Maybe add some code examples to your question, it's hard to say what needs to be mocked without some idea about the implementation.

Comment: @GlenSwinfield App connects to server using paramiko. I will post some useful code here on monday.

Comment: So you need to force client.connect(ip, username='root') to raise an exception?

Comment: @GlenSwinfield I want client.connect(ip, username='root') to get TRUE not exception so my idea is to bring up mock server with response online = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you need to patch paramiko. Like this:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

from mymodue import ssh_server

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('mymodule.paramiko')    
    def test_server(self, paramiko):
        ssh_server(server_list, timeout=200)
```

No exception will be raised, and therefore `client.connect(ip, username='root')` will get TRUE.

What this is doing is mocking the paramiko module where it is imported into your module - it will be an instance of MagicMock, which will return further instances of MagicMock whenever its methods are called. So, ultimately `client.connect(ip, username='root')` will just return an instance of MagicMock, it will never try to connect to anything, your code won't be using paramiko at all.

Depending on what you are testing you might then inspect the paramiko variable in your test method to assert that it has been used in the way you intended, i.e. its methods have been called correctly. The mock.patch  documentation will help you to do that: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html

Comment: What does the paramiko in _def test_server(self, paramiko):_ doing?

Comment: the patch decorator replaces paramiko in your module with an instance of MagicMock, and passes that same instance into your test method. This achieves 2 things:

1) It means that the paramiko module is mocked
2) It means you can make assertions against the MagicMock to see how paramiko was used in your method, and prime it to return specific responses. It's all in the docs I linked to.